# Windows Phone - SqlCeException column type double

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a base entity and 3 inherited sub-entities, called NoteItem, ImageItem and MapItem. The base entity class is marked with the [InheritanceMapping] attribute and has a Discriminator column. Everything works fine, except the third MapItem entity, which contains 4 columns of type double and bool.

For example, if I insert the a NoteItem entity it will throw an exception:

> SqlCeException - Column Pitch can not contain NULL values

Pitch is column with double type. Only if I extend the [Column] attribute of each double and bool column with the CanBeNull = true addition, then it works.

It seems to me that there's a problem with double and bool values, because a column with type string must not explicitly contain the CanBeNull addition.

Is this a known problem or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there's a problem with double and bool values

AFAIK the behavior is by design.

> a column with type string must not explicitly contain the CanBeNull addition

A string CLR value can be null, thus without `[Column( CanBeNull = false )]` attribute specified, the entity framework generates column that can be null. OTOH, bool and double values can't be null, if you want to allow nulls, you must specify `[Column( CanBeNull = true )]`

If you don't want to decorate your double and bool properties/fields with `[Column]` attributes, you could e.g. define them as `double?` and `bool?`, respectively.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Does the questionmark ? indirectly set the [Column] attribute CanBeNull to true or how does it work?

Comment: The question mark changes your field/property type from double to "double?" which is a short form of System.Nullable<double>.. It will affect your code that reads values of those fields/properties.